# Hosting my own website

Tags: ubuntu, web-hosting

I know that I can use ubuntu server to host a website, but what I was wondering if it is possible to host a website on the regular version of ubuntu and not the server edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Apache runs on pretty much anything, so you can host a website on pretty much anything you have.

The main different between Desktop and Server versions is that the desktop has additional things you would like on a desktop (such as a GUI, office apps and so on) and the server version adds things that are useful only on a server (LDAP support, virtualization, power management, etc).

The thing is, though, because it's all just based on packages, there's no reason why you can't start with the Desktop version and add the server features you want or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple website, you can also try the lightweight [NginX](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)